# How to use gulp changed or newer with the same folder being src and dest?

Tags: javascript, gulp

But as it compares the files, being the same folder, it gets a bit obvious that if they compare the same files, always be the same but I need the source and output files to be in the same folder, if anyone knows a solution, I will stay thankful.
Like this example:

```js
function webpConvert() {
    return src(folder + "/**/*.{jpg,png}")
        .pipe(newer(folder))
        .pipe(
            parallelCore(
                webp({
                    quality: 100,
                    lossless: true
                })
            ),
            os.cpus().length
        )
        .pipe(dest(folder))
}
```

I'm using gulp4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible use *Gulp-newer or Changed* in cases of the same folder for both src and dest. You can use *gulp-cache-files* or *gulp-file-cache*.